# How do I make the code @header and @members be in Lexer not Parser with ANTLR?

Tags: parsing, antlr

Let's say I have a grammar file with this code.

```
// START:members
@header {
using System.Collections.Generic;
}

@members {
public static Dictionary<string, string> memory = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

ANTLR puts the code in Parser like this.

```
public partial class Eval : TreeParser
{
 ... 

    /** Map variable name to Integer object holding value */
    //HashMap memory = new HashMap();
    Dictionary<string, int> memory = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Is there way to put the code in Lexer not Parser with ANTLR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@header` and `@members` is short for `@parser::header` and `@parser::members` respectively.

To put code in the lexer, do: `@lexer::header` and `@lexer::members`.